# The table is not inserted correctly in the <div> block

Tags: html, css

I try to insert the table in the div block, but then the page is displayed incorrectly.

This code:

```xml
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="description col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-12 clean-left">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Add Income doc"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-6"><i
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> Add product</i></button>
                <div id="dynagrid-1" class="grid-detail" style="font-size: inherit;">
                    <div id="w44" class="grid-view is-bs3 hide-resize"
                         data-krajee-grid="kvGridInit_35174e0a"
                         data-krajee-ps="ps_w44_container">
                        <div class="rc-handle-container" style="width: 0px;"></div>
                        <div id="w44-container"
                             class="table-responsive kv-grid-container">
                            <table class="table">
                                TEST
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Gives the following result:

[image]

If I delete tag  then I get correct result:

```xml
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="description col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-12 clean-left">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Add Income doc"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-6"><i
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> Add product</i></button>
                <div id="dynagrid-1" class="grid-detail" style="font-size: inherit;">
                    <div id="w44" class="grid-view is-bs3 hide-resize"
                         data-krajee-grid="kvGridInit_35174e0a"
                         data-krajee-ps="ps_w44_container">
                        <div class="rc-handle-container" style="width: 0px;"></div>
                        <div id="w44-container"
                             class="table-responsive kv-grid-container">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

How I can paste table in this area?

Comment: You should add more code as you have on your images or create snipet

Comment: Please add a snippet for more clarification..!